# Plotting multiple date/price sequences on same plot, dates are out of order

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to track price fluctuations for multiple items on the same graph. The dates for each item will be in order, but the dates between items might vary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_list = [OrderedDict([('2018-09-01 00:00:00', 70.0), ('2019-03-04 00:00:00', 75.0)]),
           OrderedDict([('2018-03-01 00:00:00', 27.5), ('2018-04-01 00:00:00', 82.5), ('2018-09-01 00:00:00', 27.5)]),
           OrderedDict([('2016-07-01 00:00:00', 37.0), ('2016-10-01 00:00:00', 37.0)])]

for item in my_list:
    plt.plot_date(*zip(*item.items()), linestyle='solid')

plt.tick_params(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

My chart is out of order. It plots the dates from the first item in the right order, but then adds the first date from the second item to the end of the chart, instead of at the beginning.

[image: Output Chart]

How do I get the x-axis dates to be in order? It would be even better if any months that don't have a plot point were also included, so as to show the months passed between 2018/09/01 and 2018/03/04.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your dates aren't dates, but strings.

Comment: Oh you're right. I just needed to convert to datetimes.